# Test with Robolectric and Google Play Service throw me “AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-play-services, robolectric

i have a Android project with Google play services and Robolectric test in same module, other package.
I have this in my manifest:

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/gms_version" />
```

And this in integer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="gms_version">@integer/google_play_services_version</integer>
</resources>
```

But when i run the test i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I tried to put this tag directly in the manifest but i get a nullpointerexception getting this value..
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Robolectric are you using? This was a bug where robo assumed all metadata to be strings, but should have been fixed (I'm using 2.3 and this works fine)
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/950

An alternative fix is to just put the integer value in the manifest directly instead of referencing it, but guessing that's not what you're looking for...

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. It seems like it is doing the resLoader.getValue(resName, "") call, but it returns null. The package it is using seems to be incorrect though. I get for resname the following: ResName{com.app.package:integer/google_play_services_version}